# Can the sum of the cardinalities of the intersections of all pairs of sets be expressed as a function of the cardinalities of the individual sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3787555/how-to-select-the-columns-of-a-binary-feature-matrix-to-obtain-minimal-overlap/3787940#3787940) I described a task where a set $G_0$ of objects each possessing some 'features' is split into *2* (disjoint) sets $G_1$ and $G_2$, corresponding to (not necessarily disjoint) sets of features $F_1$ and $F_2$, respectively, such that the overlap of *features* between the two sets is minimal.

A user suggested a quadratic programming formulation, which can in fact be turned into a linear programming one.

I think (and please correct me if I am wrong) that the fundamental reason why the linear formulation is possible is that:

$|F_1 \cap F_2| = - |F_1 \cup F_2| + |F_1| + |F_2|$

Given that the initial total number of features $|F_1 \cup F_2|$ is a constant, and $|F_1 \cap F_2|$ is the overlap one wants to minimize, it is sufficient to make sure that the sum of the cardinalities of the individual sets $F_i$ is minimal to achieve the desired goal.
I.e. there is not need to compute (directly) the cardinality of set intersections, which is not a linear operation (is it?).

In a comment to the post I hinted to the fact that it would be desirable to extend this to cases where *more than 2* sets are formed from $G_0$.

However, I suspect that in such cases it would not be possible to use a linear formulation.

Suppose you want to form 3 sets $F_1, F_2, F_3$. Then:

$|F_1 \cup F_2 \cup F_3| = |F_1| + |F_2| + |F_3| - (|F_1 \cap F_2| + |F_1 \cap F_3| + |F_2 \cap F_3|) + |F_1 \cap F_2 \cap F_3|$

Like before, the cardinality of the union of all sets is a constant, and the quantity to minimize (between round brackets) is the sum of the cardinalities of all pairwise intersections.
However, now a new term appears, namely the cardinality of the intersection of all 3 sets, which I don't know how to express as a function of cardinalities of intersections of fewer sets, and in fact I don't even know if it is theoretically possible.
Obviously with 4, 5 or more sets the situation becomes even more complicated.

**What do you think? Is it at all possible to 'eliminate' the undesired terms, meaning expressing them in terms of cardinalities of intersections of fewer sets, or not?**

Example:

$X = \{O_1(A,B), O_2(F,Y), O_3(B,D), O_4(B,X), O_5(X,Y), O_6(A,C), O_7(E,G), O_8(X,Z) \}$

where $O_i$ represent the objects and the letters between round brackets are their features. There are 10 features in total.

If you split $G_0$ into 2 sets of 4 objects each, a possible solution is:

$G_1 = \{O_1, O_3, O_4, O_6 \}$
$F_1 = \{A, B, C, D, E, X \}$
$G_2 = \{O_2, O_5, O_7, O_8 \}$
$F_2 = \{E, F, G, X, Y, Z \}$

The feature overlap $|F_1 \cap F_2|$ is 1 (feature $X$), and indeed $|F_1| + |F_2| - |F_1 \cup F_2| = 11 - 10 = 1$.

If instead you split $G_0$ into 4 sets of 2 objects each, it appears that minimizing the sum of the cardinalities of the individual sets does not guarantee a solution where the sum of all pairwise overlaps is also minimal.

I am wondering whether one could split $G_0$ iteratively.
I.e. to make 4 sets of 2 objects, make first a subset with 2 objects and one with 6 objects, then split the latter into 2 and 4, and so on.
Something tells me that this won't provide an optimal solution (in terms of sum of all pairwise overlaps), but I am not sure.

Comment: Your very first equation about union and intersection has them swapped. That's easy to see by taking $F_1 = F_2 = \{3\}$,  a single-element set.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to correct it.

Comment: Also: this purports to be a question about elementary set theory, but it's all jumbled up with stuff about objects and features, which have no meaning in elementary set theory. Even the title question makes almost no sense: for instance "of all pairs of sets" is an infinite collection in most logics, unless you quantify it somehow,  Did you mean to ask "Is there a function $f$ of two arguments such that for *any* two sets $U$ and $V$, with respective cardinalities $p$ and $q$, the sum $s$ of the cardinalities of $A\cap B$, taken over all $A \subset U$ and $B \subset V$ equals $f(p, q)$?"?

Comment: @JohnHughes : unfortunately this is the real-world, jumbled-up task I have to deal with. I am pretty confident it has something to do with mathematics, but I am not sure under which exact branch of mathematics it falls, which is partly why I am asking the question in a forum where experts can advise and direct me, if they want to help. The title is indeed imprecise, as I could not write the whole question there. If it can be expressed better, I accept any correction. Thanks.

Comment: Well...one possible rewrite is the one I gave. Is it what you were asking?

Comment: Let me also be clear: the reason I wrote my proposed version was that YOUR version was  incoherent junk. I tried to read it -- I really did -- but so many notions were undefined that it made no sense. So I tried to help with a rewrite, and you ignored it. By the way, the answer to my rewritten question is "no".

Comment: For only 2 sets I have it. My question is about more than 2 sets. I saw that someone already asked about the _notation_ for the [sum of the cardinalities of all pairwise intersections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672275/notation-for-sum-of-intersection-cardinalities). So I would say that my aim is to know if a function $f$ exists, such that the quantity I want to minimize, $\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} |X_i \cap X_j| = f(|X_1|,|X_2|,...,|X_n|)$.

Comment: Re your further comment, sure, don't worry, and in fact I really appreciate your taking the time to try and disentangle this mess. I take your point about my notation not being clear, and that's because indeed I don't know under what theory this falls. Is there no concept in set theory of the map from the objects a set contains to the set of features the objects themselves contain? Because in many applications this is a central and very consequential concept. How would you represent the set of features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "no," at least in all the interesting cases.

I'll restate the question in several forms, because even after comments it's still ambiguous.

Form 1: If there a function $f$ from $n$ integers to $1$ integer with the following property:  Given any collection of sets $X_1, \ldots, X_n$,
$$
\sum_{1\le i < j \le n } |X_i \cap X_J| =f(|X_1|, \ldots |X_n|).
$$

The answer to this version is "no" because we can look at two examples with $n = 2$:

$$
A: X_1 = \{1, 2\}, X_2 = \{1, 2\}\\
B: X_1 = \{1, 2\}, X_2 = \{3, 4\}.
$$
In both examples, we have $|X_1| = |X_2| = 2$, so we need for $f(2,2)$, whatever it may be, to be the value of the left-hand side.

In both examples, there's exactly one intersection to consider, namely, $X_1 \cap X_2$. In the $A$ example, this has cardinality $2$; in the $B$ example, it has cardinality $0$. So $f(2,2)$ must be both $2$ and $0$, which is impossible.

I suspect that this is the case of greatest interest to you, at least for inspiration if you ever do formulate the question you really wanted to ask.

Form 2: Is there a function $f$ from $n$ integers to $1$ integer with the following property:  Given the collection $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ of **all** subsets of some set $A$, we have
$$
\sum_{1\le i < j \le n } |X_i \cap X_J| =f(|X_1|, \ldots |X_n|).
$$

Yes. If $A = k$, then $n = 2^k$. Each item in $a$ appears in exactly $2^{k-1}$ of these, and since there are $k$ items in $A$, the left-hand sum is exactly
$$
k 2^{k-1}
$$
The sizes of the subsets, which are the arguments to $f$, range from $1$ to $k$, so this can be expressed by defining
$$
f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \max_i (x_i) 2^{(\max_i x_i)-1}.
$$
Alternatively, because the number $n$ of arguments is known, and must be a power of two, we could just write
$$
f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \log_2(n) \frac{n}{2},
$$
which shows that the function might as well be a constant function.

Form 3: Given a **partition** $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ of some set $U$, i.e., a collection of disjoint subset of $U$ whose union is all of $U$, is there such an $f$?

In this case, the answer is yes! For the left-hand side will consist of pairwise intersections, which are all empty, so the left hand side is a sum of zeroes, hence is zero. The constantly-zero function $f$ works!

To answer your question about "features" and "objects" -- set theory has nothing to say about these, much as chemistry has nothing to say about impressionism vs fauvism, even though both kinds of paint use chemicals.

Comment: Thank you, I think you answered the question in the form I put it, although that's not what I meant to ask. The closest is form 1, but I should have asked if $f$ exists such that $\sum_{1\le i < j \le n } |X_i \cap X_j| =f(|X_1|, \ldots |X_n|, |X_1 \cup ... \cup X_n|)$. I think then for $n=2$ the answer is yes, as per my first formula, whereas for $n\ge3$ I suspect it's no. However, this discussion made me realize that I don't strictly need to have this type of $f$. I might be able to make a linear formulation of my problem by adding more variables, namely those encoding each $|X_i \cup X_j|$.

Comment: Again, sorry for not being clearer; this is a real-world problem, which I am not able to express in a very formal mathematical way, but it has important applications. The connection between objects in a set and the features of the objects in it is made in linear programming contexts by constraints that link the variables encoding the objects themselves and the variables encoding the features, via appropriate matrices.

Comment: It's certainly "no" for $n = 3$. Example A: $X =\{1,2,3,4\}, X_1 = \{1,2, 3\}, X_2 = \{2, 3, 4\}, X_3 = \{1, 3, 4\}$, so $f(3, 3, 3, 4) = 6$; Example B:  $X =\{1,2,3,4\}, X_1 = \{1,2, 3\}, X_2 = \{2, 3, 4\}, X_3 = \{1, 2, 3\}$ so $f(3,3,3,4) = 5$.

Comment: Yes. I think the formula is: $\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} |X_i \cap X_j| = (n-1) \cdot \sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} |X_i| - \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} |X_i \cup X_j|$. Which is compatible with a linear programming formulation, although it requires a number of variables that increases more than linearly, I think $O(n^2)$.

Comment: But then in fact, thinking about it, just as well to encode directly the pairwise intersections :/ Same number of variables, still $O(n^2)$, but more direct. Probably only to discover that the system has so many variables that it's computationally unfeasible for any real set :)

Comment: Of course, I have no idea what you're talking about -- I don't do optimization or linear programming really -- but I'm glad you've gained some sort of insight.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, merely a reformulation that utterly ignores the incorrect characterization in the title of the Question.

Let $F$ be a set, called the set of features; each element of $F$ is a feature.  Let $O$ be a set, called the set of objects; each element of $O$ is an object.  Let $h:O \mapsto \mathcal{P}(F)$, where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes powerset, be a map from objects to sets of features.

For each $n$-member partition of $O$, $\{G_1, G_2, G_3, \dots, G_n\}$, let $F_i = \bigcup_{g \in G_i} h(g)$ for $i \in [1,n]$, be the set of features present in at least one object in $G_i$.  We define the "overlap" of such a partition of $O$ to be
$$  \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j = i+1}^n |F_i \cap F_j|  \text{.}  $$

You wish to study the minimum of the overlap as we range over partitions of $O$ with between $b$ members and $B$ members, for $b,B \in [2,|O|]$ and $b \leq B$.  That is, over
$$  \bigcup_{n = b}^{B} \{  \{G_1, \dots, G_n\} \text{ is a partition of $O$} \}  \text{.}  $$

Does this seem to capture your intent?

---

And now to some questions in your Question.

> I.e. there is not need to compute (directly) the cardinality of set intersections, which is not a linear operation (is it?).

This is not an interpretable question.  What sort of "linear".  Here is an answer directed toward linear time complexity:

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets.  Create an associative array from "elements" to "number of occurrences", so the default value of an array lookup is $0$.  For each element $a \in A$, look up $a$ in the associative array, increment that value, and write the result back into the array.  The array now returns $0$ for anything not in $A$ and $1$ for any element of $A$.  Repeat the lookup, increment, write process for each $b \in B$.  Now, read out the array: each element with count $2$ is in the intersection of $A$ and $B$.  This process is linear in $|A|$, then in $|B|$, then in $|A \cup B| \leq |A| + |B|$, so has linear time complexity.  (The above assumes unit time (or bounded time) array operations.  One might object that the time to insert into or perform a lookup in the underlying data structure is not linear time complexity.  But, it's bounded by the logarithm to the base $2$ of $|A \cup B|$, so at worst multiplying the time complexity by a logarithm.  So the time complexity may be a little worse than linear, but it is not as bad as quadratic.)

---

I observe that a problem instance can be represented as a bipartite graph: where edges represent the "has" relation (the function $h$ in the above), there is a collection of objects vertices and a collection of features vertices.  The problem is to partition the objects to minimize the number of features "had" by more than one partition.  This is a [notorious problem](https://ipads.se.sjtu.edu.cn/zh/publications/ChenAPSys14.pdf) (see section 2.2. et seq. there) which does not have efficient solutions (at least not linear time and certainly not implemented as linear programming).

Comment: Thank you! Your reformulation up to the overlap formula captures exactly what I meant to describe. Then the problem I need to solve is: identify one partition of $O$ _with a specified $n$ and with a specified cardinality for each $G_i$_, which minimizes the overlap. In the example I mentioned at the end of my post, the partition needed to have  $n=4$ and 2 objects in each $G_i$.

Comment: As for the linear programming part, linearity, etc, my point is the following. Suppose you encode features as bits of a binary vector. E.g. if the ordered set of all features is $\{A,B,C,D\}$, vector {1,0,0,1} encodes a features set $F_i$ containing features $\{A,D\}$. Then, the number of features contained in _both_ $F_i$ and $F_j$, i.e. their 'overlap', is the dot _product_ of their vectors, which normally requires quadratic programming. For $n=2$ I had observed that $|F_i \cap F_j|$ can be expressed as a function of $|F_i|$'s, and I wondered if the same could be done for $n>2$.

Comment: I'll need to look better into your second point. For now I found a way to implement this in linear programming, but just writing out the explicit 'intersection' variables. E.g. if binary variables $y_{i,k}$ encode the presence of the $k-th$ feature in $G_i$, and binary variables $z_{i,j,k}$ encode the presence of the $k-th$ feature in _both_ $G_i$ and $G_j$, I just need to link them using constraints $z_{i,j,k} \ge y_{i,k}+y_{j,k}-1, \forall i,j,k | 1\le i < j \le n , k \in [1,m]$, where $m$ is the total number of distinct features.